# Meaning of Brownian motion to distribute as Normal distribution

Tags: brownian-motion

Let $B(x)$ be a Brownian motion.
We know by definition that $B(x+1) - B(x)$ ~ $N(0,1)$.
I am trying to understand if that means that $B(x+1)-B(x) = PDF(x)$, where PDF(x) is the probability density function of $N(0,1)$ at the point $x$.

Can you tell me if its right? and if it isnt, what is the actual meaning of $B(x+1)-B(x)$ ~ $N(0,1)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where the confusion is raising, but I'll try.

If we define

$$
\Delta_{x} := B(x+1) - B(x)
$$

we see that this variable is normally distributed. What is this? It is the **increment**.
This means that if at step $x$ we are at $B(x)$ we can find where we will be at $x+1$ using

$$
B(x+1) = \Delta_x + B(x)
$$

but $\Delta_x$ is a random variable! This means that we can have certain probabilities of being somewhere in the next step.

For simplicity, let's image that at $x=0$ we start from $B(0)=0$. It means that

$$
B(1) = \Delta_0
$$

which is a normally distributed random variable!
The gaussian probability tells you that the *probability density function* of $B(1)$ is gaussian. So, in this case, you will have a high probability of being around $0$ at the next step and a lower probability of being far from it.

I've used your notation here, but I suggest using $t$ instead of $x$ as it is more intuitive to understand that it is the time.

Answer (score 0):

$B(x+1)-B(x)$ is a random variable which follows a standard normal distribution, that is, for each Borel set $A$ of the real line,
$$
\mathbb P(B(x+1)-B(x)\in A)=\frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_A\exp\left(-t^2/2\right)dt.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your comment. How can i use this definition to find B(x+1)-B(x) in a specific point x? because the integral is not defined on a single point.

Comment: What do you mean by "find $B(x+1)-B(x)$"? x

Comment: I mean that if i need to find x (if exists) such that B(x+1)-B(x) > 3 for example, i thought about using the connection to normal distribution to say that B(x+1)-B(x)~N(0,1), but i dont know how to move forward from here... how the relation to N(0,1) helps me find if there exists x such B(x+1)-B(x) > 3